# Integers to Matrix (cvMat)

Tags: c++, opencv

Hey guys, 
I'm working on a project. I need to use the function cvFindHomography in openCV before this step I have applied LK optical flow function, so I get the features in the first frame and in the second frame as INTEGERS, well in cvFindHomography I need to use these features but as cvMat not as integers.

Do you have any I idea how to put these integers in a Matrix in order to use them in the function mentioned above.

Thank you.

Comment: You should post some code if you want the answers in usable code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the cvMat() constructor:

```
CV_INLINE CvMat cvMat( int rows, int cols, int type, void* data CV_DEFAULT(NULL))
```